# Open cart website server response time is big

Tags: opencart

My open cart website is too slow so how can I solve the issue. When I open the admin side its working good and fast but when I open front-end site then its to load my site. I remove my image folder and check whats problem but again the same problem. if anyone has a solution so please tell me how to resolve it.

Comment: "if anyone has a solution so please tell me how to resolve it" well  you need to give us more info such as: 1. OpenCart version? 2. Theme used? 3. List of extensions installed.

Comment: Thanks but my problem is solve.

Comment: Why don't you update the post to help others then?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to use a Cache module that would implement speed optimization features like image compression, caching, file minification and CDN

here are two top extensions:

[Carbon Cache - OpenCart speed Optimization for Google page speed](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=35620&filter_search=cache)

[Nitro pack](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension&filter_search=cache)

### check for errors

You need to check if you have any issues in your Log file (system/storage/logs/error.log) and if you do, correct them. errors can cause speed drop.

### flatten category structure

Also, a heavy category structure with lots of subcategories can influence your speed as well so try to keep your categories flat (3 subcategories deep max)

### too many modifications are bad

Modifications like OCMOD can also create speed issues since they can implement bad code directly into the core. so watch out for those.

### find a better hosting

And last but not least - your hosting provider. Check if your hosting is actually providing you with a fast server. We often suggest opting for Digital Ocean since the guys have done a good job providing high-quality servers for a reasonable price. if you want [$10 when signing up](https://m.do.co/c/935df05bec8e) with DO and feel comfortable if we also get $10, use our Digital Ocean link, or just visit their website [digitalocean.com](https://digitalocean.com/)